# Worshipping lord Shani even when I have good Effects of Lord shani in my life

Tags: worship, shani, peepal-tree

Lord Shani is favourable in my birth chart and does me good, but I still worship lord shani. I place a diya with musturd oil and black til at a peepal tree at saturday nights and I offer him water also.
I have heard that if people do such worship, then lord shani will remove his malefic effect from thier life.I want to ask that I am also worshipping him this way, will the favourable effects of lord shani also be removed from my life?

Comment: Yes, you can worship when Saturn (or any other planets) is non-malefic/ exalted or so on....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the fact is, Lord Shani, in the simplest words, is the lord of Justice. He is the "Karma fal Daata". All his actions towards you is based on your sole actions towards others.You must learn that helping others and behaving well with others is the key to make him happy. And if you still want to worship him, there is no ill effect of it. Worshiping never has any ill effect on anyone.It is meant for good.

Comment: Nice Answer Keep It Up.Pls.cite some sources in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Understand that you can never control what is going to happen this Saturday, all you can control is what will happen inside of you everyday.

However instead of worshiping Shani dev why not worship our own planet mother Earth plant more trees, Yajna (is done for entire universe), Worship Sun and moon, at least you can see and feel Sun, Moon and Earth.

I am not denying that there are no effects of other planets on us, may be there are, Well i do not know, what we know is sun is the Source of energy for Mother earth and we should do something about it as well.

We are made up of 5 elements which are in entire universe, Why not worship water, air, Earth, fire and Akash.

I just believe that if we are discussing anything, we should get gain out of it, to have more knowledge.

hope it helps.

Comment: You have followed a more scientific approach to your answer but it doesn't fit in religious beliefs.

Comment: Religious mind should be free from physiological fear of superstition.

Comment: Yes superstition has totally changed the way people see religion. Religion has become a matter of fear.