# Can people wear iron ring even when they already have good effect of Lord Shani in their lives?

Tags: astrology, shani

I wanted to know if the ring will nullify even  the good effects of lord Shani from their lives.

Comment: Your related [Worshipping lord Shani even when I have good Effects of Lord shani in my life](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17092)

Comment: It could have been very nice if you could also add some valuable answer alongside the comment.

Comment: See my edit.. now the Q is ok.. if u do not like my edit then revert it but then the Q mite be closed.. so it's better u keep my edit. @AnishSharma Wait for answers.. someone or the other mite very well know the answer.

Comment: IMO opinion u can still wear iron ring when sani is benefic in ur chart.. for malefic sani they prescribe the horse-shoe ring to be worn if i am not wrong.. so that's not just an ordinary iron ring..but one that's obtained from a particular source.@AnishSharma

Comment: @Rickross mine is made from boat nail. It is similar to horse shoe.

Comment: @AnishSharma Oh ok.. then i am not sure.. i am only aware of horse shoe rings being used as Sani's remedy. But i am not sure if this remedy is a traditional Hindu one or not..probably it's from the Lal Kitab

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. The rule is you should only give strength to planets that are good for your chart. This is the parasari principle. Gemstone or metals does exactly that. It strengthens the planet. On the contrary, if Saturn is inauspicious for your chart, you should not wear it. In that case, you should do pujas (Graha Shanti).

Comment: How can you find out if it works?

Comment: "You can easily check whether astrologer's prediction works or not." Really? Then you would be famous all over the world.

Comment: " if that happens to your life, then prediction works". Actually, it is a lot more complex than that. You see it 's extremely hard to track a certain result to a prediction.

Comment: If I find some money on the ground and astrology said I would find money somewhere how do you know they were talking about this money? It's impossible to determine.